# How can I solve this? "A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Tags: c#, copy, move, ioexception

I've recently started using Visual C# because I thought it would be interesting to try something different than Unity for once. So I tried to make a program, that searches through set directories, grabs files based on the extensions I need, and then moves them into a folder.

Now I have figured out the directory scan and filtering out all, the extensions I need using DirectoryInfo and FileInfo lists, which is not causing any evident problems. What's killing me is the FileInfo.MoveTo method. I set a string variable, which you will see below, as a path. Then placed that as the string argument for MoveTo. Everything seems to make sense, and it works when I put "target.Name" as it moves the files to the root, but won't work if I put "Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()" Or any other directory other than "target.Name" because it's itself.

Apologies for the lengthy question, but this is really killing me.

```
static List<FileInfo> _targetFiles = new List<FileInfo>();
static string _targetPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        CopyFiles(_targetFiles, _targetPath);
        Console.WriteLine("Scan finished.");
        Console.Read();
    }
static void CopyFiles(List<FileInfo> files, string path)
    {
        foreach (FileInfo target in files)
        {
            try
            {

                target.MoveTo(_targetPath);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine(target + " moved to " + _targetPath);
                Console.ResetColor();

            }
            catch
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("TRANSFER FAILED: " + target);
                Console.ResetColor();
            }

        }
    }
```

Output:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Console

```
TRANSFER FAILED: filename.ext
```

Comment: A directory is not a file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I get the question properly. When you are using current directory (`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();`), then it seems that you are trying to over-write your exe and dlls.

second you need to provide a fully qualified path as file name. A directory path maps to a folder.

Comment: The files I'm moving is just images currently as just a test and so is the directory, gathering a bunch of files of the same types that I define, then move them to a different location.

As for the second, do you mean the path that includes the file name? Because I have not attempted to do that, I will now though and get back to you on that, thank you.

Comment: You are using Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); check what path is it pointing too.

Comment: Wonderful! It works, I just added "+ target.Name" to the end of the directory! And Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); was just a place holder because I already knew where it was at, a test. And I had a console output on where it outputs to so I knew where to check to see if it worked. 

Thank you for the help, it's the small things that kills me.